# single signin between python cgi and python django

Tags: python, django, cgi, django-authentication, django-login

There are one project using Python Django, another stand alone project using python cgi. Both has it own user auth. module. What would be a simple way to merge user management together?
 I mean signin already built in python cgi, i want to use the same signin for python django, how i can pass authenticated user_id and username from python cgi to python django.currently i am using mysql database for both application

usually in django we will passing  authenticated user as follows in views.py

```
user = request.user
```

But signin is built using python cgi, how can i pass athenticated user from python cgi to python django(views.py)

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps create a custom [authentication backend](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/customizing/#writing-an-authentication-backend) in your Django app, which sends authentication requests to your cgi app?

Comment: share the code what have you tried

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use one of the **Django** [authentication middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/middleware/#module-django.contrib.auth.middleware) like [RemoteUserMiddleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/middleware/#django.contrib.auth.middleware.RemoteUserMiddleware) or [PersistentRemoteUserMiddleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/middleware/#django.contrib.auth.middleware.PersistentRemoteUserMiddleware).

They are middlewarer for utilizing Web server provided authentication.

You can see [Authentication using REMOTE_USER](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/auth-remote-user/#authentication-using-remote-user) for usage details.

> When the Web server takes care of authentication it typically sets the
>   **REMOTE_USER** environment variable for use in the underlying
>   application. In Django, **REMOTE_USER** is made available in the
>   **request.META** attribute. Django can be configured to make use of the
>   **REMOTE_USER** value using the **RemoteUserMiddleware** or
>   **PersistentRemoteUserMiddleware**, and **RemoteUserBackend** classes found in
>   **django.contrib.aut**h.

Answer (score 0):

you need to do a single sign on, take a look at this

https://github.com/namespace-ee/django-rest-framework-sso

personally i use an ldap database to store the users, everytime a user is accessing my app for the first time, a query is sent to a server where i have a rest api set up which verifies if the user logged in before, and didn't log out.